# Make load page in SLXNA Game [WP7]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm working on a game for Windows Phone 7, I'm using version SLXNA (Silvelight + XNA) and everything I have, the problem is that it takes a lot to navigate the game page (GamePage.xaml), I want to make a page that says "loading ..", because the application stays where it is until you see the game page.

Thanks for your answers. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)
- [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- Async code

It really depends where do you want the loading to happen. Is it a game loop or a SL page.  XNA Thread example:

```
    private Thread thread;
    private bool isLoading;
    private void LoadResources()
    {
        // Start loading the resources in an additional thread
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(gameplayScreen.LoadAssets));

        thread.Start();
        isLoading = true;
    }
```

For example LoadResources method is called when user press tap the screen

```
        if (!isLoading)
        {
            if (input.Gestures.Count > 0)
            {
                if (input.Gestures[0].GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
                {
                    LoadResources();
                }
            }
        }
```

In the game update loop

```
        if (null != thread)
        {
            // If additional thread finished loading and the screen is not
            // exiting
            if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped && !IsExiting)
            {
               //start the level
            }
        }
```

It's good idea to show something to the user e.g.

```
        private static readonly string loadingText = "Loading...";
```

and in the draw loop

```
        if (isLoading)
        {
            Vector2 size = smallFont.MeasureString(loadingText);
            Vector2 messagePosition = new Vector2(
                (ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - size.X) / 2,
                (ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - size.Y) / 2);
            spriteBatch.DrawStringBlackAndWhite(smallFont, loadingText, messagePosition);
        }
```